# Docker and Kubernetes installed on Ubuntu 20.04 but I cannot get the docker container to reach outside traffic

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ubuntu-20.04

I had an Ubuntu 20.04 server which was used for CI/CD and it was using Docker on it to build and publish images.

The resources were not that much requested so I decided to install Kubernetes on that server to add a second master node to my k8s cluster.

Therefore I ran `kubespray` on it as a Master node and the installation completed successfully. Since the install of k8s I get a strange issue.

Using the command line `kubectl exec -it podname -- sh` I can do a `nslookup google.com` and it works fine.

```
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4020:805::200e

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.13.142
```

Once I used the `docker exec -it ubuntu bash` command line I cannot resolve any dns entry once in a pure docker container not using kubernetes layer.

The docker daemon uses the kubernetes dns to resolve. In the file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-dns.conf` it is setup as

```
Environment="DOCKER_DNS_OPTIONS=\
    --dns 10.233.0.3 --dns 127.0.0.53  \
    --dns-search default.svc.cluster.local --dns-search svc.cluster.local --dns-search lan  \
    --dns-opt ndots:2 --dns-opt timeout:2 --dns-opt attempts:2"
```

Is it possible to run pure docker container on a k8s node?

### Update

After a while passed at debugging I figured out it is not the a DNS issue but rather the entire traffic not able to get outside the docker network.

I figured this out when I tried to use `apt update` and I could see it was able to resolve the repository address but in no way it was able to reach the mirror.

Until I have more time I will just host another cicd server and not mixed k8s node with anything else.

Comment: Be careful about trying to configure docker to use what appears to be a CNI address without teaching it about the full CNI setup; AFAIK docker does its own network management, so 10.233.0.3 might not mean anything outside of kubernetes (Service and Pod addresses are figments of your Node's imagination). The rest of the question is: if you have kubernetes on the Node, why do you want to run "bare" docker anyway? Seems self defeating

Comment: They are images built and published to a registry to be later on used on the k8s cluster.

Comment: So you reference k8s hostnames in your `Dockerfile`s? If so, are you sure you wouldn't be happier with DIND or kaniko inside your cluster?

Comment: I do not reference any kubernetes hostname. As I wrote before installing kubernetes on the node I was using it as our CI/CD server were we built our code inside Docker images and published them to a registry. Once I installed kubernetes on top of it. Then docker builds started to fail. While debugging even more I think dns is fine, but it can't reach the outside.

Comment: Trying to update the container using apt it find the ip address of the mirror but can't reach it. ```docker run -it --rm ubuntu bash                                                                                                                                                                                                          
root@6bd674f81144:/# apt update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:```

Comment: Can you paste above information into post ?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a DNS problem, that appears to be a proxy problem (if I were guessing)

Comment: Possible, yes, Advisable, absolutely not.
If you're running K8s on a host don't try and do anything manually within Docker. If you do want to run stuff manually just assume it's not within your cluster.

Comment: @Timothyc I didn't wanted it to be considered within the k8s. I only wanted the docker daemon to run outside the k8s context but didn't wanted to waste resources for nothing. Since I didn't figured out how to get it to work I am building a new node.